# Why is my PDF size from my InDesign Export still large?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, file-size, compression

I'm doing class project that is a four-page, seven-image document with very little text. The project must be submitted as a PDF under 300 KB. However, when I export the document under the smallest file size preset and with the compression rates down to 72 dpi, I get a PDF that is 612 KB.

All my classmates are able to get it under 300 KB, so I'm confused as to why mine is so large. I'm using 5 JPGs and 2 GIFs, and each take up a 5in by 5in square in the document. They are relatively really small pictures (avg. 250 KBS) and I've even re-saved all to be under 100 KB, but the PDF size only drops to around 500 KB I transferred between InDesign CC on Mac and InDesign CS5 on Windows and wonder if that is a concern.

Comment: 5 jpgs at roughly 100kb each = 500kb, add the gifs, and anything else and... well... Using vector data or less raster images would reduce the size further. Beyond this, no one can really answer this question.

Answer (score 6):

There is so many methods that reduce your PDF make sure you follow one of it or you may need "in some cases" to follow all of them. some when you export from indesign and some in Acrobat itself as a post production process.
you can reduce the PDF by one of the following method.

1. RGB color mode is less in size than CMYK
2. images embeded in the document may be very huge, check the image size and its color mode too.
3. when you intend to save your work to PDF in indesign make sure to select a PDF smaller PDF preset. notice that [high quality preset] is a profile produce large file than [smallest file size]
4. you may want to define a new custom preset by [define...] a new preset and make sure to deselect from the tones of the options that make your PDF smaller in size. like ((a.de-check embed page thumbnails b.check optimize for fast web view c.dont export all layers and don't preserve exporting layer)) see the following image
   [image]
5. in the compression options make sure to downsampling all you picture to a reasonable sizes. and check all option as marked in the attached image.
   [image]

now for the produced PDF file you may optimize its size within Adobe Acrobat itself. by an action optimizing the PDF for web and mobile view as show in the next screen capture
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order to get a small size pdf i would suggest trying; file - save as - pdf(interactive) instead of pdf(print)... You will get a smaller file i believe...