# Combining multiple Illustrator files into one PDF

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pdf, workflow, adobe-acrobat

For my work I use a combination of Photoshop, Illustrator, Visio, Excel and other things to make pictures and diagrams. I then want to combine them into one large PDF. Combining multiple files to PDF in Acrobat Pro works for the non-Photoshop/Illustrator filetypes, but for whatever reason doesn't work with AI or PS.

Is there a way to take advantage of this useful tool to work on Adobe's own products (the supported formats does not list .ai or .psd)? Going through and exporting each to PDF can be tedious.

Comment: Actually, even if *.ai isnt listed it will work (set option to all files first). Its just that it will result in HUGE pdf files and you certainly dont want to do this.

Comment: Additionally, once you used the technique of Guadalupe below, you can then optimize your pdf even more to lower the file size: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/49315/file-size-issue-when-exporting-from-word-2013-to-pdf/55355#55355

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have access to InDesign I think that your best option is to place all of your files in one InDesign file and then export your InDesign file as one PDF file. This really simplifies your process especially if you're going to be updating the original .AI or .PSD files at any time. You may even be able to place your other non Adobe files into the InDesign file in their original file type or as PDFs. This can even help you with your pagination and page order.

Answer (score 0):

> Going through and exporting each to pdf can be tedious.

I am worried of something. Do you actually want a salad of page sizes, proportions, styles and fonts?

Or you want a solid document?

If you want a solid document, you need actually to make a document. Guadalupe already recomended that using Indesign. You can also use Ilustrator Itself, or Scribus which is free. Then the pdf export is a single click process.

If you want the salad option...

Comment: Thanks for the input. In general, design aesthetic doesn't matter. I do patent law and most patent attorneys unfortunately make their figures using a combination of paint, powerpoint, and the back of napkins, so how nice something looks takes the backseat to efficiency. I had been doing separate Ai files for each page, but I think I'll just do different artboards and then export as one pdf. Then I can mix in visio/excel docs as needed. If something gets too complex I'll try sending it through to in-design (although I have little experience with it, it sounds like a good solution). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I just save each Ai files as a pdf under the "save as" option , then use the pdf program called nitro pro ,it has a function to combine and arrange pdf files , very simple and easy to use